# How to show future date using DateUtils

Tags: java, android, date, android-dateutils, apache-commons-dateutils

I'm creating app. It's a news list where on every news I need to show date, e.g. 9 hours ago or 1 month ago and so on. Also I have future news, so I need also to show e.g. after 1 month. So I'm using `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` for this purpose. But I only can show past dates, e.g. 9 hours ago or 1 month ago and I can't show future dates. It shows the future date like Jun 26, 2020. So is there a way to show it e.g. after 2 month using `DateUtils`?

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            millis,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS).toString();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216141/dateutils-getrelativetimespanstring-for-future-dates

Comment: That's cool, but what means the "in n days" in accepted answer?

Comment: No I just simply can't understand what means the "in n days" in that accepted answer

Comment: According to the linked documentation (in the accepted answer) `Time spans in the future are formatted like "In 42 minutes"`. If you want days, you can use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MLLIS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you same way but time spans in the future are formatted like "In 42 minutes"

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            futureTimeInMillis,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS).toString();
```

You can pass one of 0, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, HOUR_IN_MILLIS, DAY_IN_MILLIS, WEEK_IN_MILLIS
in last parameter.
Last parameter is the minimum resolution means 
by which format you want.

MINUTE_IN_MILLIS - `In 42 minutes`

HOUR_IN_MILLIS - `In 2 hours`

DAY_IN_MILLIS - `In 2 days`

Comment: Actually I will accept your asnwer. I used DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY. If I will select DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, can I see my past dates like 2 days ago or  9 hours ago?